# Use of random intercepts and slopes in combination with factor-smooth interaction

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have built two gams in `mgcv`. `wt3` runs fine but `wt4` struggles to run (I have terminated it every time due to taking too long to run).

I suspect that `wt4` does not run because it does not make sense to include a factor-smooth interaction (`s(age.x, scale_id, bs = 'fs', k = 4)`) that creates a separate smooth for each individual (`scale_id`) through time (`age.x`), and then additionally include a random intercept for individuals (`s(scale_id, bs = "re")`). However, I would like some confirmation that my thought process is correct (or not).

So my question is: does it make sense/is it possible to include a factor-smooth interaction that creates separate smooths for each individual through time, and then also include a random intercept or random slope for individuals?

````
wt3 <- gam(weight_t ~ 
             tagged +
             sex + 
             s(age.x, scale_id, bs = 'fs', k = 4),
           data = long, 
           method = "REML")    
 

wt4 <- gam(weight_t ~ 
             tagged +
             sex + 
             s(age.x, scale_id, bs = 'fs', k = 4) + 
             s(scale_id, bs = "re"), 
           data = long, 
           method = "REML")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, and it shouldn't matter too much as the `fs` basis is fully penalized; if the intercepts in the `fs` basis aren't needed then they should get penalized to ~0.

If you have a large number of levels in the `scale_id` factor, then it could well be that you are just hitting the main drawback of using the penalty-matrix version of a random effect; namely that it is not as efficient as dedicated GLMM software that can take account of the sparse nature of the random effects.

You should turn on tracing via the `gam.control()` function passed to the `control` argument of `gam()` to monitor what is going on during fitting. If there is a problem you might be able to diagnose it from the trace output, but usually when I've had issues with a model converging, I've hit the preset iteration limits and received a convergence warning from *mgcv*, which makes me think you're just hitting a computational bottleneck by adding in another set of random effect terms.